# Excel VBA - Import from a closed Workbook in the same Folders

Tags: vba, excel, import

I'm trying to import some data from a closed workbook in the same folder into my active workbook. This is what i have so far

```
Sub Import_Data()

Dim rng As Range
Dim WB2 As Workbook
Dim FName As String
Dim c1 As Worksheet
Set c1 = Sheets("c")

FName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\_w" & Format((WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now) - 1), "00")
Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FName)

ThisWorkbook.ChampSpecific1.Range("L3:O6").Value = WB2.Worksheets(2).Range("M3:P6").Value

WB2.Close

End Sub
```

When I run the macro i get the error "Method or Data Member Not Found" highlights `ThisWorkbook.C1.Range` (The c1 Part). It should be pulling the Worksheet "c" shouldn't it?

Best Regards

Comment: Can you remove `ThisWorkbook` from the line and check it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `ThisWorkbook.` from `ThisWorkbook.ChampSpecific1.Range("L3:O6").Value` and it should work. Like this:

`ThisWorkbook.ChampSpecific1.Range("L3:O6")`

The problem comes, because you have already pjut a set on `ChampSpecific1` worksheet and it knows his `Parent`. Thus, if you try to refer a new `Parent`, it does not like it.

To get the `Parent` write the following `Debug.Print ChampSpecific1.Parent.Name` on the line before the error.

Comment: That works thanks. Next issue is that it doesn't copy and paste the values from WB2 to ChampSpecific1. Does the Worksheets(2) part of the code select the sheet that is second from the left?

Comment: @Dullspark - Just write `debug.print Worksheets(2).Name` and check it out yourself.

Comment: Where do i write it down? Should it just show something when i run the macro? - Found it - Put it into the Immediate Window. That's useful to know thank you

Comment: @Dullspark - welcome. In the immediate window you can also write `?Worksheets(2).Name` instead. It is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `ThisWorkbook` qualifier as it's already set. Try this (using `SourceSht` and `TargetSht` to keep things from getting confusing:

```
Sub Import_Data()
Dim SourceSht As Worksheet
Dim TargetSht As Worksheet
Dim FName As String

FName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\AIMS_Report_w" & Format((WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now) - 1), "00")

Set SourceSht = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FName).Worksheets(2)
Set TargetSht = Sheets("Summary-Champion Specific")

TargetSht.Range("L3:O6").Value = SourceSht.Range("M3:P6").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: That works thanks. Next issue is that it doesn't copy and paste the values from WB2 to ChampSpecific1. Does the `Worksheets(2)` part of the code select the sheet that is second from the left?

Comment: Yes, that would refer to the 2nd from left sheet. Answer edited to fix and simplify.